# binding model property to custom element input

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to bind a custom element input data to a parent model property:
The this.fieldValue of the custom element should be eventually binded to the registration.firstName property of the container\parent page.
See related code:
This is the custom element HTML:

```
<template>
   <label>
       ${title}<input name.bind="fieldName" custom-type="text" 
                 title.bind="title" focusout.trigger="focusoutAction()" />                           
  </label>
</template>
```

This is the view model (simplified):

```
import {inject, bindable, customElement, bindingMode} from   
'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('form-input')
@inject(Element)
export class FormInputCustomElement {
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;
@bindable title;
@bindable customType;
@bindable placeHolder;
@bindable fieldName;
@bindable onFocusout;



constructor(element) {
   this.element = element;
   this.input = null;
   this.fieldValue = '';
}

bind(bindingContext) {
  this.input = this.element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  this.input.type = this.customType || "text";
  this.input.placeholder = this.placeHolder || "";
}

  focusoutAction() {
    this.fieldValue = this.input.value;
    this.onFocusout();
  }
}
```

In the custom element I can see that the this.fieldValue get the input text.
This is the container relevant code:

```
<template>
<require from="./../../formControllers/formInput"></require>

  <div>
    ${fieldValue}<form-input name="firstName" id="firstName" field-
    value.bind="registration.firstName" title="First Name" 
    validate="registration.firstName" place-holder="Enter first name" field-
    name="firstName" on-focusout.call="validateInput()" />
</div>

<button type="button"  click.delegate="createNewAccount()">Create New 
 Account</button>
```

And this is the class relevant code:

```
import { inject, bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';
export class AccountRegistration {

constructor() {
   this.initRegistration();
}

initRegistration() {
    this.registration = {};
    this.registration.firstName = '';
}

createNewAccount() {
var a = this.registration.firstName;
}
```

The problem is that when I reach the createNewAccount function, the 
this.registration.firstName is empty although it is binded to the custom element 
field-value (fieldValue in  camelCase) property, which is set to the input text of the custom element.
What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think The problem is 
    `@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) value;`

This should be  `@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) fieldValue;`

Also in your template `<input value.bind="fieldValue" />`

Now when you bind registration.firstname to field-value in your form it will be bound to the value on the input.